# ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "import" uniquely - React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, typescript-eslint

I am getting the below error while running the Lint test in NextJS project.

```
ESLint: 7.32.0

ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "import" uniquely.

- /Library/...[FOLDER_PATH]..../node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/index.js (loaded in ".eslintrc.json")
- /Library/...[FOLDER_PATH].../node_modules/eslint-config-next/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/index.js (loaded in ".eslintrc.json » eslint-config-next/core-web-vitals » /Library/...[FOLDER_PATH].../node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js")

Please remove the "plugins" setting from either config or remove either plugin installation.
```

Earlier the lint test was working fine. Later, I updated the dependencies version with 'yarn upgrade' and started getting this error.

Comment: add `root: true` into your config file. It stops ESLint loading other config files from ancestor directories than the config file.

Comment: And `--resolve-plugins-relative-to .`

Answer (score 2):

Though `--resolve-plugins-relative-to` also worked, importing the resolver `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` seems to work better for NextJS with Typescript.

```
yarn add -D eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

or

```
npm i -D eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```